Unexpected coefficient behaviour of sklearn Lasso for small alpha values
Here is some basic code generating a regression problem.
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import Lasso, LinearRegression

n = 100
np.random.seed(42)
X = np.random.normal(size=n)
eps = np.random.normal(size=n)

b_0, b_1, b_2, b_3 = 0.5, 2.8, 6.7, 3.4
Y = b_0 + b_1 * X + b_2 * (X ** 2) + b_3 * (X ** 3) + eps

n_cols = 10

df_X = pd.DataFrame(columns=[f'X ^ {i}' for i in range(1, n_cols + 1)])
for i in range(1, n_cols + 1):
    df_X[f'X ^ {i}'] = X ** i


I was looking at how Lasso shrinks the coefficients when I noticed something odd. The coefficient values for X variables that are raised to powers greater than 3 (variables redundant to the real problem, but that increase variance of the model) have coefficients of almost 0 for alpha/lambda equal to 0. I've checked what are the coefficients for OLS and they are very non-zero :




betas OLS
betas Lasso




const
0.3
0.3


X^1
2.2
2.5


X^2
5.8
6.9


X^3
5.3
3.7


X^4
3.0
-0.03


X^5
-2.0
-0.14


X^6
-2.4
0


X^7
0.8
0


X^8
0.7
0


X^9
-0.1
0


X^10
-0.07
0



Theoretically Lasso with alpha/lambda = 0 should produce the same results as OLS. I've found that here a similar question was asked and I understand that as the documentation for Lasso states:

When alpha = 0, the objective is equivalent to ordinary least squares, solved by the LinearRegression object. For numerical reasons, using alpha = 0 with the Lasso object is not advised. Instead, you should use the LinearRegression object.

Ok, sure, makes sense, numerical issues. But why are the results so different even when alpha is not equal to zero, but for example 0.00001, or 0.001, or 0.1?
If you look at the plot of shrinking coefficients I've produced, you will notice, that the initial high values of coefficients for X^4/5/6/7/8 are completely omitted in what Lasso produces. Or maybe they begin to come into picture at lasso~=0.5, but that is also when they start being shrunk.

Code for generating the plot:
lambdas = np.concatenate((np.linspace(0, 1 - 1e-8, 1000), np.linspace(1, 200, 1000)))
coefs_path = []
for l in lambdas:
    model = Lasso(alpha=l)
    model.fit(df_X, Y)
    coefs_path.append(model.coef_)
coefs_path = np.array(coefs_path)

for i_var in range(df_X.shape[1]):
    plt.plot(lambdas, coefs_path[:, i_var], label=f'$X^{{{i_var+1}}}$')
plt.title('Shrinking coefficients')
plt.xlabel('$\lambda$')
plt.xlim(left=-1, right=10)

# I have a different part of code where I use sklearns' LassoCV, but that is irrelevant here.
lasso_cv_alpha_ = 0.28
plt.axvline(lasso_cv_alpha_, lw=2, linestyle='--', color='#49eb34', label=f'Best coefficients ($\lambda$ = {lasso_cv_alpha_:.3f})')

plt.legend();

Is this an expected behaviour? Because it doesn't feel like it is.
Edit based on Jordi Pastor comments:
Indeed changing the Lasso model parameters to Lasso(alpha=l, max_iter=int(1e6), tol=1e-16) produces non-zero coefficients for X^4/5/6/7/8/9/10 variables. They are still way off compared to OLS as presented below




betas OLS
betas Lasso (tol & max_iter)




const
0.3
0.3


X^1
2.2
2.7


X^2
5.8
6.0


X^3
5.3
2.8


X^4
3.0
2.1


X^5
-2.0
1.0


X^6
-2.4
-1.3


X^7
0.8
-0.5


X^8
0.7
0.2


X^9
-0.1
0.07


X^10
-0.07
0



Here is an updated plot of the shrinking coefficients with the changed model parameters. I've changed the range on the x-axis for better visibility of the small alpha/lambda values.

Again the results are odd to me. The coefficients start at the values that are above in the betas Lasso column, but they drop almost immediately to zero. To be clear, the max_iter and tol parameters were set for all model runs.
To be honest now this is even more odd to me.

I am afraid I could not follow. Where are the fitted betas? Can you include how you generate the design matrix and fit the models in your question?

The fitted betas are in the table.
I've added the code for producing and plotting the shrinking coefficients.

My first guess is that the features end up with quite disparate scales, and so numerical precision causes the problems. Do you get any convergence warnings?

Thanks for your comment. Somehow I was expecting the b_0, b_1, b_2 and b_3 to be fitted and I was confused. I reproduced the code and yes, as Ben comments, it produces a massive flood of ConvergenceWarning. Can you try scaling your features (which should be done afaik if you plan to regularize)?

Scaling the features avoids the flood of ConvergenceWarnings but  _coordinate_descent.py:631: UserWarning: Coordinate descent with no regularization may lead to unexpected results and is discouraged..  Scaling back the coefficients lead to a similar result:  array([ 2.56805449e+00,  6.99045177e+00,  3.77910366e+00, -3.32666943e-02,
-1.39937684e-01, -2.62737362e-04,  3.89838989e-04,  3.53451585e-04,
1.87952385e-03, -2.90885274e-05])

@JordiPastor similar results (scaling features then recalling coeffs) with very small but positive alpha?

@BenReiniger, quite better! using max_iter=int(1e6), tolerance and alpha set to 1e-16 gives the following coefs (scaled back):
array([ 2.71187018,  6.09788064,  2.85438583,  2.19301792,  1.04535008,
-1.39275245, -0.51085083,  0.26781171,  0.07343242, -0.00850835])
(ConvergenceWarning still pops up)

@JordiPastor, I've added some updates using your findings. Do you have an idea for an explanation of this behaviour of sklearn's optimization? The coefficients taking incorrect non-zero values for extremely small alpha/lambda and than immediately going to zero?

I came to this question not because I am knowledgeable about it but because I was curious. I have not a deeper intuition than "scale your features if you want to have a similar (in scale) penalty across them". That being said, the convergence warning / Lasso documentation leads to coordinate_descent which I did not know before participating to this thread. Adding wikipedia as well
